# Out of bounds 4>=4

Tags: java

Why is it running out of bounds?
I just can't see why is it running out of bounds.

```
for(int g=0;g<tblDependent.getRowCount();g++)
{
    insertdep.execute("INSERT INTO EmployeeDependentTable Values('"+
       txtEmpNumber.getText()+"','"+
       tblDependent.getValueAt(g, 0)+"','"+
       tblDependent.getValueAt(g, 3)+"','"+
       tblDependent.getValueAt(g, 1)+"','"+
       tblDependent.getValueAt(g, 4)+"','"+
       tblDependent.getValueAt(g, 2)+"')");
}
```

Comment: What's the title about? Is that what the error says?

Comment: From the error message, it's clear that your table only has `4` columns.  So, when you invoke `tblDependent.getValueAt(g, 4)`, you are attempting to access the 5th column, which doesn't exist, hence the exception.  In `4 >= 4`, the first `4` is your input, whereas the second `4` is the first out of bounds value.

Comment: Use `PreparedStatement` http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 5):

I guess the problem is with this part

```
tblDependent.getValueAt(g, 4)+"','"+
```

there is possible no 5th column, assuming that the column indices are zero based.

Comment: The title suggests that it is failing on the call you mention. That suggests that `tblDependent.getValueAt(g, 0)` works, which would mean your assumption is correct.

Comment: the table columns is 5

Answer (score 1):

The error message says "Out of bounds 4>=4".

That means `tblDependent.getValueAt(g, 4)` is probably causing problems.

You probably only have 4 columns, and so `getValueAt(g, 4)` raises an OutOfBounds exception.

#### Side Note

Please worry about SQL injection.